# Outlook Add-In For Different Hours For Different Days

Tags: outlook-addin

Not sure why MS, has not done this, and i cannot even find a plug-in, so the "work time", can have different times on different days. Typically, if someone has not done it, it cannot be done.

This is my first dive into Outlook, so not sure, if this can be done. Ultimately, i would like this to go into the space space in Outlook, when the work time is set.

Is it possible to modify that section (file->options->calendar ->work time)?
If so, what parts of the API do i need to look at?
any secondary approaches, such as "outside" code to modify the needed sections?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: This is not a dev question. You can post Outlook improvements/suggestions at https://outlook.uservoice.com/

Comment: Been there, but i am asking if it is really even possible to get that deep. I just have not done anything with the inner workings of Outlook, so have no clue what functions and methods are open, or if what i need to get to are in the private scope.

Comment: No, not possible, Outlook only looks at the options it is aware of.

Comment: That is what i was afraid of. Thanks for the reply, and saving me days of homework, to find out it is sealed.